# jquery mobile slider control with tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.0

I want exact control like this in jquery mobile.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/tabs.html

but instead of showing the different tabs i want to retrieve the tabid in alert box.

do we have the same control for jquery mobile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event handler to the `change` event for the jQuery Mobile Slider Widget and use it's value as an index. You would set the slider to accept values from zero to the number of tabs minus one (0-2 if you have three tabs):

```
$('#my-slider-id').bind('change', function () {
    var index = this.value;
});
```

You can then use this index to select the ID of one of the tabs. The tabs will be in a parent element, so you can select that element and then select the child with the same index as the slider:

```
$('#my-slider-id').bind('change', function () {
    var newID = $('#tab-parent-id').children().eq(this.value)[0].id;//remember that `this.value` is the current index

    alert('The selected tab is: ' + newID);
});
```